# How to get the "From" Code to work with the HTML Body of the Email using PHP Mail?

Tags: php

Here is the interesting  part, if I remove the `$from` code, it will properly render the html email like it supposed too.  If I add the `$from` code back in, the `$from` will work properly but show the entire html script code in the body of the email.  I am trying to figure out how to get the from and the html email to work properly together.  I have tried the `\n\r` and `\r` but nothing works.  It's one or the other with this code.

```
$from    = 'MyOwnEmail';
$to      = $email;
$subject = 'Test ';
$message_body = '<html><html>';

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers = "From: $from"; 
mail( $to, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
```

Comment: That‘s because you are _overwriting_ `$headers` every time ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
>  $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
>  $headers = "From: $from";
> ```

Each time you assign a new value to `$headers`, you **replace the old value**.

So you need to look up how to put multiple headers into the variable. See [the documentation for the additional headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> String to be inserted at the end of the email header.
>
> This is typically used to add extra headers (From, Cc, and Bcc). **Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).** If outside data are used to compose this header, the data should be sanitized so that no unwanted headers could be injected.

So you still need a string, but it has to be one string with all the headers in it, and the need to be separated by new lines.

The cleanest way to do this would be to put all the headers in an array and then join them.

```
$header_list = [ 'MIME-Version: 1.0', 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1', "From: $from" ];
$header = implode("\r\n", $header_list);
```

Comment: I have not tried to combine them together as an array, let me test that and see if it works.  I am not familiar with headers. Thanks for the information.

Comment: This did not work,  It did not show the from whoever and showed the html code in the body of the email.  Side Note, I always received the emails.   It did not do one or the other.  This is tested with gmail.

Comment: Its works, I figured out what was wrong.  The above statement worked.

Answer (score 0):

Append headers instead of overwriting.

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from"."\r\n";
```

Comment: That won't work. You've put the content type and from headers as parts of the mime-version header instead of as headers of their own. You need new lines between them.

Comment: Already tried that example with the \r\n and did one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Solution - Fixed with Quentin Help  -- Thanks

```
$from    = 'MyOwnEmail';
$to      = $email;
$subject = 'Test ';
$message_body = '<html></html>';

$header_list = [ 'MIME-Version: 1.0', 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1', "From: $from" ];
$header = implode("\r\n", $header_list);

mail( $to, $subject, $message_body, $header);
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin for helping me out.